# Is this did agreed with previous remoteness or independent from it?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> "There, there, get up, child," she said heartily. "Of course I forgive you. I guess I was a little too hard on you, anyway. But I'm such an outspoken person. You just mustn't mind me, that's what. It can't be denied your hair is terrible red; but I knew a girl once—went to school with her, in fact—whose hair was every mite as red as yours when she was young, but when she grew up it darkened to a real handsome auburn. I wouldn't be a mite surprised if yours ***did***, too—not a mite."
>
> –– L. M. Montgomery, Anne of Green Gables

I’m just wondering if native English speakers really perceive ***did***, remoteness expression, as is said in grammar books. Or is it in the same line with the backshifted tense expressions, that is, they don’t perceive it as a remoteness, but regard the preterite in ***did*** is agreed with the previous remote expression, ***would***. Am I thinking wrong? (I'm not so sure for I can recollect expressions not following the agreement.)

Comment: I'm not sure about native speakers, but isn't that *did* required because it must have happened before the time the speaker says *I wouldn't be surprised*?

Comment: @DamkerngT.- No, actually it means *does at sometime in the future* It can be replaced with *does* without changing the meaning.

Comment: @Listenever- I'm not sure what you mean by *perceive*.  I take it to mean, *hear it and understand its meaning* and I'd say, "Yes, we do perceive it."

Comment: To clarify a little I believe the use if *did* here is because the implied reference time for the statement is *when the child is grown up*, and she is saying that by the time she is grown up, her will have darkened.  But we can shift the implied reference time to now by changing *did* to *does* without changing the meaning of the statement.

Comment: @Jim, so true! My bad. I didn't read the whole passage. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "do" acts as a sort of pronoun, like "it", but for verbs. (And of course "do" and "it" go together sometimes:

> I want to jump on a trampoline. Me too, I want to do it! [ "do it" = "jump on a trampoline" ]

In that sentence, we have:

> when she grew up it *darkened to a real handsome auburn*. I wouldn't be a mite surprised if yours *did*, too.

*did* simply stands for *darkened to a real handsome auburn*. It can be replaced by that verb phrase without changing meaning.

That is what is perceived by the native speaker.

As an aside, although this phrase looks identical to the one in the previous sentence, it is altered semantically in that it becomes subjunctive.) This shift is illustrated by a verb that undergoes a form change into the subjunctive to suit the mood of the conditional.

> Your parents and siblings *are silly*. I wouldn't be surprised if you *were*. [*were* stands for the earlier *are silly*, altered to subjunctive to fit the grammar.]

This is not so different from pronouns changing cases to fit the site of their use:

> That is Mary. I know *her*. [Mary is replaced by *she*, which alters to *her*]